# If statement inside awk to change a value

Tags: perl, if-statement, awk

I have the following file

```
...
MODE P E
IMP:P 1 19r 0
IMP:E 1 19r 0
...
SDEF POS= 0 0 14.6 AXS= 0 0 1 EXT=d3 RAD= d4 cell=23 ERG=d1 PAR=2
SI1 L  0.020
SP1    1
SI4 0. 3.401                                                                    
SI3 0.9 
...
NPS 20000000
```

I want to do the following task

1. Check if after the sequence `ERG=` there is a number or a string.
2. If it's a string, find the sequence `SI1 L` and change the value after that, using values that the user inputs.
3. If it's a number, change the number using values that the user inputs.

Note that if after `ERG=` there is a number, there will be no `SI1 L` sequence.

For instance number 2 can be accomplished using the following

```
#! /bin/bash

vals=(0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05)

for val in "${vals[@]}"; do
  awk -vval="$val" '$1=="SI1"{$3=val}1' 20
done
```

How can the above algorithm be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  #!/bin/bash

val="$@"

awk -v val="$val" '
  BEGIN { i=1; split (val,v," ") }
  # If it is a string, find the sequence SI1 L and change the value after that, using values that the user inputs
  /SDEF POS.*ERG=[a-zA-Z]+/ { flag="y" ; }
  /SI1 L/ { if (flag=="y") { $3=v[i]; i++; flag="n"; } }
  # If it is a number, change the number using values that the user inputs.
  /SDEF POS.*ERG=[0-9]+ / { sub(/ERG=[0-9]*/, "ERG="v[i],$0);i++; }
  1
' file
```

hints:

If the rule find ERG with at least one or more letters ([a-zA-Z]+, it will set the flag.
The /SI1 L/ rule will only triggers, if the flag is set. If the rule triggered, it would unset the flag again, so that any following /SI L/ wouldn't trigger again.

.* stands for 0-n sign or character

[A-Za-z]+ stands for 1-n alphabetic character in lower or upper case

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is that your code only works for `SI1 L `. It doesn't work if after `ERG=` there is a number.

Comment: Right, I replaced EXT= with ERG=

Comment: Correct! Can you edit your answer to replace `EXT` in the last line? In addition, I can't understand the `flag` commands you are using, the `POS.*` as well as the `+` symbol after `[a-zA-Z]` and `[0-9]`.

Comment: I can understand that `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]` and `[0-9]` look for any letter and number, but I cannot understand the `+` after the brackets. Also I cannot understand the `POS` and what is the purpose of `flag="y" ;` and the change to `flag="n";`. Could you enlighten me, please?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]=]' -v string_value="foo" -v number_value=42 '
    /ERG=/ { 
        for (i=1; i<NF; i++)
            if ($i == "ERG") {
                isstring = ($(i+1) ~ /[^[:digit:]]/)
                break
            }
        if (!isstring)
            $(i+1) = number_value
    }
    /SI1 L/ && isstring { $NF = string_value }
    1
' filename
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Your code works if after `ERG=` there is a string(so there is `SI1 L ` followed by a number) but it's not working if after `ERG=` there is a number.

Comment: Ah, is it an integer or a float?

Comment: I tried with an integer and it adds `number_value` at the end of each line. http://pastebin.com/f2TCPhNT

Comment: Now that I see it, it always adds `number_value` at the end of each column.`

Comment: Thank you once again for your edit! The problem now is that the output has the value of `number_value` at the end of the line `SDEF POS= 0 0 14.6 AXS= 0 0 1 EXT=d3 RAD= d4 cell=23 ERG=d1 PAR=2`

Comment: I am trying to understand your code... What does `~ /[^[:digit:]]/` do?

Comment: that is a regular expression that matches one character that is not a digit.

Comment: I see! I still can't get your code to work. Whatever the scenario, I always get the value of `number_value` at the end of the `SDEF` line.