# [a-z]+, [A-Z]+, [0-9]+ and flag commands in awk

Tags: regex, awk, flags

I am trying to understand some commands in awk, which are related to [If statement inside awk to change a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318040/if-statement-inside-awk-to-change-a-value/21320743?noredirect=1#21320743) question.

The input file is

```
...
MODE P E
IMP:P 1 19r 0
IMP:E 1 19r 0
...
SDEF POS= 0 0 14.6 AXS= 0 0 1 EXT=d3 RAD= d4 cell=23 ERG=d1 PAR=2
SI1 L  0.020
SP1    1
SI4 0. 3.401                                                                    
SI3 0.9 
...
NPS 20000000
```

and the code is

```
#! /bin/bash

vals=(0.02 0.04)

for val in "${vals[@]}"; do
awk -v val="$val" '
  BEGIN { i=1; split (val,v," ") }
  # If it is a string, find the sequence SI1 L and change the value after that, using values that the user inputs
  /SDEF POS.*ERG=[a-zA-Z]+/ { flag="y" ; }
  /SI1 L/ { if (flag=="y") { $3=v[i]; i++; flag="n"; } }
  # If it is a number, change the number using values that the user inputs.
  /SDEF POS.*ERG=[0-9]+ / { sub(/ERG=[0-9]*/, "ERG="v[i],$0);i++; }
  1
' 20small > "${val}"
done
```

I am trying to ubderstand the following

1. Why after `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]` and `[0-9]` there is the `+` sign? I can understand that those commands search for any letter and number after the defined sequence, but I don't seem to understand what does the `+` do.
2. What exactly does `flag` do? I can understand that `/<expresion>/ flag="y"` "replaces" the `<expresion>` with `y`. I can't seem to understand the reason to change the flag a few lines bellow. Is it like a dummy flag?
3. What exactly does `/    /` do? I know that this declares the search pattern. Why adding `SDEF` and `POS`? Just to be sure it's the correct line? I also find confusing the use of `.*`. Does it mean *Find `SDEF POS` line and on the same line look for `ERG` no matter what it's between them*? What exactly does `/SDEF POS.*ERG=[a-zA-z]+/` do?

I am a rookie in `awk` so I am trying to learn it by example. An help would be more that welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `+` means one or more repetitions.  For example, `a+` will match `a` `aa` `aaa` etc.  `a*` match same as `+`, but also none `a`
2. flag is used as a temporary information holder.
3. `/  /` is regex holder and is used to show that it must match regex inside the two `/`

I do suggest you look at some `awk` one liners and try to understand how they work. Also start by reading some `awk` tutorials.  You can find a lot by using Google.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! More questions though. Why add the new flag i.e. `flag="n"`? It's a useless info, isn't it? In addition what does `.` do? For instance what does `/SDEF POS.*ERG=[a-zA-Z]+` do?

Comment: `.` represent any characters.  Flag is changed from `y` (yes) to `n` (no) to tell its done with some operation, to prevent repeating. I like flag with `0` or `1` but anything can do. `/SDEF POS.*ERG=[0-9]+ /` mans a text starting with `SDEF POS` then some or more unknown characters `.*` then `ERG=` then one or more digits `[0-9]+`. Eks it will match this line `DATA SDEF POSME TOERG=3445356`

Comment: I see!!! It means yes or no... Now it make4s perfect sense!!! Thank you very much!!!